# How to begin multiple sessions with Extensible Storage Engine

Tags: winapi, esent

In the documentation for [`JetBeginSession`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg294131(v=exchg.10).aspx), it notes that the *session* is the unit of granularity that defines a transaction, it defines where the cursor is in your currently open table, it defines the currently active index. On one session nothing else can be done. But they do note:

> To increase concurrency and parallel access to the database, multiple sessions can be begun.

Which is what i would like. I would like to open a second *session* to the database.

### Background

The ESE is somewhat convoluted in how you get it going:

```
JetCreateInstance(out instance, "UniqueInstanceName"); //Create a uniquely named instance of the ESE in our process

JetInit(instance); //initialize the instance
   JetBeginSession(instance, out sessionID); //initialize a session on the instance
      JetAttachDatabase(sessionID, filename); //attach a database file to our session
         JetOpenDatabase(sessionID, filename, "", out databaseID, 0); //open the database file in our session

            //...now we can open table, get data, etc
            //E.g. JetOpenTable(sessionID, databaseID, "Customers", null, 0, JET_bitTableReadOnly, out tableID);

         JetCloseDatabase(sessionID, databaseID);
      JetDetachDatabase(sessionID, filename);
   JetEndSession(sessionID, 0);
JetTerm(instance);
```

And that all works.

### But how do we open another session?

The ESE documentation, while sparse, does hint at the ability to have multiple sessions going for the same database:

> - To increase concurrency and parallel access to the database, multiple sessions can be begun.
> - `JET_bitTableDenyRead` - The table cannot be opened for read-access by another database session. *(implying that sometimes it **can** be opened for read-access by another session)*
> - `JET_bitTableDenyWrite` - The table cannot be opened for write-access by another database session. *(implying that sometimes it **can** be opened for write-access by another session)*
> - [`JetOpenDatabase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269299(v=exchg.10).aspx) - This function can be called multiple times for the same database.
> - `JET_bitDbExclusive` - Allows only a single session to attach a database. **Normally, several sessions can open a database.** *(emphasis mine)*

The naive approach would be to begin another session:

```
//Startup the instance
JetCreateInstance(out instance, "UniqueInstanceName");
JetInit(instance);

   //Make first session
   JetBeginSession(instance, out sessionID);
   JetAttachDatabase(sessionID, filename);
   JetOpenDatabase(sessionID, filename, "", out databaseID, 0);

      //Startup second session
      JetBeginSession(instance, out session2ID);
      JetAttachDatabase(session2ID, filename);
      JetOpenDatabase(session2ID, filename, "", out database2ID, 0);

      //Teardown second session
      JetCloseDatabase(session2ID, database2ID);
      JetDetachDatabase(session2ID, filename);  <----hangs
      JetEndSession(session2ID, 0);

   //Teardown first session
   JetCloseDatabase(sessionID, databaseID);
   JetDetachDatabase(sessionID, filename); 
   JetEndSession(sessionID, 0);

//Terminate instance
JetTerm(instance);
```

Except the call to `JetDetachDatabase` in the second session hangs.

- Checking the documentation of `JetDetachDatabase` gives no help.
- Checking the`JetAttachDatabase` we come across something worrying.

There's an error code the implies it is an error to try to attach a database that has already been attached by a different session:

> JET_errDatabaseSharingViolation: The database file has already been attached by a different session.

### How to open multiple sessions?

So now rather than flail about too randomly, i'll ask for the correct way to do it.

> How to begin multiple sessions with Extensible Storage Engine

### Bonus

I did flail about somewhat randomly. If the call to `JetDetachDatabase` is hanging, lets just not call it! It completely violates the documented rules:

- `JetOpenDatabase` says i must call `JetAttachDatabase` first
- `JetAttachDatabase` says i must call `JetDetachDatabase`

But trying it:

```
//Startup the instance
JetCreateInstance(out instance, "UniqueInstanceName");
JetInit(instance);

   //Make first session
   JetBeginSession(instance, out sessionID);
   JetAttachDatabase(sessionID, filename);
   JetOpenDatabase(sessionID, filename, "", out databaseID, 0);

      //Startup second session
      JetBeginSession(instance, out session2ID);
      JetOpenDatabase(session2ID, filename, "", out database2ID, 0);

      //Teardown second session
      JetCloseDatabase(session2ID, database2ID);
      JetEndSession(session2ID, 0);

   //Teardown first session
   JetCloseDatabase(sessionID, databaseID);
   JetDetachDatabase(sessionID, filename); 
   JetEndSession(sessionID, 0);

//Terminate instance
JetTerm(instance);
```

And it actually *seems* like it ***happens*** to work.

...yay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did in your "flailing" was the correct way to access the database from multiple sessions.

`JetAttachDatabase()` opens the file and associates it with an instance. It only needs to be called once.

`JetOpenDatabase()` opens a handle to the database within the session and can be called on each session.